# Converting int to string

Tags: c++, string, int

Here `str2` is a string I need to append and `str1` is the string I append onto `str2`. After I append last to `str2` I need to append a number (`int cnt`) to `str2`. So I am using the below code, which came to my mind and it is working. Is it wrong to code like this, since I saw the usage of `string s = lexical_cast<string>(a);` and  `itoa (i,buffer,10);`  implementations where compiler complaints about the library.

```
    string str2;
    string str1;
    int cnt;
    str2 += str1 ;
    str2 += char(cnt+48);//cnt converted to ASCII char and appended;
```

Comment: @FedericoReghenzani I went through the thread you suggested earlier, it does not discuss anything about code snippet shown here

Comment: @ajax_Velu C++ isn't BASIC :P ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This statement

```
str2 += char(cnt+48);
```

is bad. Firstly it uses magic number 48. It would be better to write at least as

```
str2 += char( cnt + '0' );
```

Secondly the code will work only if cnt contains a number with one digit.

It would be better to use standard function `std::to_string` For example

```
str2 += std::to_string( cnt );
```

Comment: Note that std::to_string was added in C++11! No mention of C++11 in tags or code.

Comment: @Conduit I wonder, at what point will we be able to assume C++11 == C++.

Comment: @zdan Once all C++ code is converted, haha. Or, realistically, once compiling using the C++11 standard no longer requires flags, I guess?

Comment: @zdan: Right now is probably about as close as it's ever going to get. If you're lucky, the question is already whether `C++` means `C++11` or `C++14`.

Comment: std::stringstream is also useful and not dependent on C++11 and allows for cout style formatting

Comment: @cppguy  You are right.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use c++11 and its `std::to_string(...)` you can use `ostringstream` class.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ostringstream ss;

    ss << 1;

    string str = ss.str();

    cout << str << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1
```